# .NET Core: attributes that execute before and after method

Tags: c#, .net-core

In Java, it is possible to use AspectJ for adding behavior before and after executing a method, using [method annotations](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html). Since C# Attributes seem to be very similar, I was wondering whether it would be possible to achieve similar behavior. I was looking in several tutorials and other sources ([1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454(v=vs.71).aspx), [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/), [3](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/827091/Csharp-Attributes-in-minutes)), but none of them helped me.

I thought that maybe I could be able to mimic the behavior by inserting the code into Attribute constructor and making it disposable, like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class MyWritingAttribute : Attribute, IDisposable
{
    public MyWritingAttribute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Attribute created");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Attribute disposed");
    }
}
```

However, when using the attribute like this, only *Hello world!* got displayed in the console:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SayHelloWorld();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    [MyWriting]
    private static void SayHelloWorld()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

I was thinking that maybe Console is not reachable in the attribute, but even when replacing it with `throw new Exception()` expressions, no exception was thrown. How is it possible that `StringLengthAttribute` from EF works, but my attribute is not even instantiated? And how do I make the attribute run before and after the decorated method?

Comment: You have to use an AOP-Framework. Attributes only extend the metainformation of types.

Comment: Attributes are metadata. They do not run at all. AspectJ works by rewriting of the compiled code after the fact -- the method annotations themselves do nothing. The best-known .NET equivalent is [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/).

Comment: You need some framework that *reads* and handles the attribute. Just having it there won´t do anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just like with Java and AspectJ, you need separate AoP tooling to inject code like this in .NET.

[PostSharp](http://postsharp.net) is one such tool, probably the best known. I belive they have support for .NET core since version 5.

Comment: Just leaving a link here to another answer I found useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60133882/3873799. This recommends Fody over PostSharp, due to its free nature (voluntary contribution) and flexibility.

Answer (score 12):

You need some framework that is able to handle your attribute appropriately. Only because the attribute exists doesn´t mean it will have *any* effect.

I wrote some easy engine that does that. It will determine if the attribute is present on the passed `action` and if so get the reflected methods in order to execute them.

```
class Engine
{
    public void Execute(Action action)
    {
        var attr = action.Method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttribute), true).First() as MyAttribute;
        var method1 = action.Target.GetType().GetMethod(attr.PreAction);
        var method2 = action.Target.GetType().GetMethod(attr.PostAction);

        // now first invoke the pre-action method
        method1.Invoke(null, null);
        // the actual action
        action();
        // the post-action
        method2.Invoke(null, null);
    }
}
public class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string PreAction;
    public string PostAction;
}
```

Of course you need some null-checks, e.g. in case the methods don´t exist or aren´t static.

Now you have to decorate your action with the attribute:

```
class MyClass
{
    [MyAttribute(PreAction = "Handler1", PostAction = "Handler2")]
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        
    }

    public static void Handler1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Pre");
    }
    public static void Handler2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Post");
    }
}
```

Finally you can execute that method within our engine:

```
var engine = new Engine();
var m = new MyClass();
engine.Execute(m.DoSomething);
```

Comment: Because `nameof` produces compile-time constants, in C# 6 you can actually use `[MyAttribute(PreAction = nameof(Handler1), PostAction = nameof(Handler2))]`, with obvious benefits.

Comment: @JeroenMostert What a great suggestion, I already found it annoying to rely on reflection whle I posted this answer. It will greatly improve stability.

Answer (score 5):

This can be accomplished using [DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/).

There is an implementation of a memory caching technique with logic that executes before the method being called. That can be extended to check for the existence of an attribute like this

```
var attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(invocation.MethodInvocationTarget, typeof(CachedAttribute)) as CachedAttribute;
if (attribute != null)
{
  ...
}
```

The code above can be inside the `Intercept` method in the Interceptor implementation. `CachedAttribute` would be your attribute.

Answer (score 4):

The question is similar to [Run a method before all methods of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192709/run-a-method-before-all-methods-of-a-class/60133805#60133805), hence the same answer applies to both.
Use https://github.com/Fody/Fody . The licencing model is based on voluntary contributions making it the better option to PostSharp which is a bit expensive for my taste.

```
[module: Interceptor]
namespace GenericLogging
{

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Constructor | AttributeTargets.Assembly | AttributeTargets.Module)]
    public class InterceptorAttribute : Attribute, IMethodDecorator
    {
        // instance, method and args can be captured here and stored in attribute instance fields
        // for future usage in OnEntry/OnExit/OnException
        public void Init(object instance, MethodBase method, object[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Init: {0} [{1}]", method.DeclaringType.FullName + "." + method.Name, args.Length));
        }

        public void OnEntry()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OnEntry");
        }

        public void OnExit()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OnExit");
        }

        public void OnException(Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("OnException: {0}: {1}", exception.GetType(), exception.Message));
        }
    }

    public class Sample
    {
        [Interceptor]
        public void Method(int test)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your Code");
        }
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod2()
{
    Sample t = new Sample();
    t.Method(1);
}
```