# ASPNet Core: Use [Authorize] with function in service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using JwtBearer authentication to secure my API. I am adding `[Authorize]` above each API and it worked.

I am using this code to add the authentication in the startup:

```
services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
        .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
        {
            options.Authority = "http://localhost:1234";
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.Audience = "test";
        });
```

I want a way to add the `[Authorize]` to a function in a service, or write a code in the function that works the same as `[Authorize]`.

Comment: What is the version of .net core are you using?

Comment: The concept you are trying to achieve called AOP. net core does not support it out of the box yet. PostSharp or Windsor Castle Dynamic proxy can make that happen for you. I suggest you to check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46000757/net-core-attributes-that-execute-before-and-after-method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `[Authorize]` without passing any parameters boils down to a call that checks whether or not the user is *authenticated*. From inside a service, that would look something like this:

```
// If any of the properties being accessed are null, assume that the user
// is not authenticated.
var isAuthenticated = httpContext?.User?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false;
```

To access `HttpContext` inside of a service, you can use [`IHttpContextAccessor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-2.2#use-httpcontext-from-custom-components). Here's a complete example:

```
public class Service
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

    public Service(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public void ServiceFunction()
    {
        var httpContext = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
        var isAuthenticated = httpContext?.User?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false;

        if (isAuthenticated)
        {
            // The user is authenticated.
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to apply an authorisation policy, you can use [`IAuthorizationService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.iauthorizationservice?view=aspnetcore-2.2). Here's a complete example of that:

```
public class Service
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;
    private readonly IAuthorizationService authzService;

    public Service(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor,
        IAuthorizationService authzService)
    {
        this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        this.authzService = authzService;
    }

    public async Task ServiceFunction()
    {
        var httpContext = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
        var isAuthenticated = httpContext?.User?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false;

        if (isAuthenticated)
        {
            // The user is authenticated.

            var authzResult = await authzService.AuthorizeAsync(
                httpContext.User,
                "PolicyName");

            if (authzResult.Succeeded)
            {
                // The user is authorised.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: To use `IHttpContextAccessor`, you might need to add `services.AddHttpContextAccessor();` to your `Startup.ConfigureServices` method.